# How to run "react-scripts start" with a different root?

Tags: reactjs, npm

For special reasons I want to share the package.json file between two folders `web` (the react app) and `mobile`:

```
▸ mobile/
▸ node_modules/
▾ web/
  ▸ public/
  ▸ src/
    README.md
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  yarn.lock
```

In my package.json file I've added this:
`"web-start": "react-scripts start",` under scripts. However, when I run it in the root folder (`/Users/edmund/Documents/src/banana-client`) I get this:

```
➜  banana-client git:(master) ✗ yarn web-start
yarn web-start v0.24.6
$ react-scripts start web
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /Users/edmund/Documents/src/banana-client/public
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Is there a way I can add a root directory?

Comment: Do you use ejected create-react-app? [`react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) is a part of CRA...

Answer (score 2):

For this particular use case, I would recommend you to go ahead with Yarn workspaces.

Using Yarn workspaces, you can have multiple projects inside a single repository with a main package.json file at root level that projects share and project level package.json that they don't share and use individually.

Running `yarn install` will install all your dependencies at the root level, which is configurable if you don't want some packages to install at root.

You can have scripts in root that can help you run internal projects in that workspace.

So your final project structure will look something like this:

```
- project_root
  - web
    - node_modules
    - package.json
  - mobile
    - node_modules
    - package.json

  - node_modules
  - package.json
```

Learn more about Yarn workspaces here: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

Look at this example here to understand it's basic usage:
https://github.com/pedronauck/yarn-workspaces-example

Comment: The question is about making `react-scripts start` search for `index.js` in a different directory not about using Yarn workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that Yarn workspaces may help you accomplish what you are after. Otherwise, you will have to eject as the configuration for the `appIndexJs` (set to `/src/index.js`) is set in `config/paths.js` in the `react-scripts` package. Once ejected, you can modify the `config/paths.js` variable `appIndexJs` to accommodate a varying appIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this workaround solved the same problem for me:

```
 "web-start": "cd web && react-scripts start"
```

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote except that it wont work that way because CRA tightly "PRESUMES" base directory. which means its config presumes node_modules is present in base directory. @MarkusL guessed right but it is wrong due to CRA style.

Answer (score 0):

Building on above answer just do:

```
"web-start": "cd web && npm start"
```